# 'lsusb' and 'lsusb -t' show different results

Tags: usb, vmware, lsusb

Having a problem with a USB device on my ESXi 7.0 host, I opened a console and started playing with lsusb:

```
[root@localhost:~] lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 0e0f:8003 VMware, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 16c0:05df Van Ooijen Technische Informatica HID device except mice, keyboards, and joysticks
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0658:0200 Sigma Designs, Inc. Aeotec Z-Stick Gen5 (ZW090) - UZB
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2341:0042 Arduino SA Mega 2560 R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0557:2419 ATEN International Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 0e0f:8002 VMware, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 0e0f:8002 VMware, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 8 channel internal hub
```

Here, only a single "16c0:05df" device and no "0bda:5411" usb hub.
Then I tried:

```
[root@localhost:~] lsusb -t
Bus#  1
`-Dev#   1 Vendor 0x0e0f Product 0x8003
  |-Dev#   2 Vendor 0x16c0 Product 0x05df
  |-Dev#  10 Vendor 0x0bda Product 0x5411
  | |-Dev#  11 Vendor 0x16c0 Product 0x05df
  | `-Dev#  12 Vendor 0x0403 Product 0x6001
  |-Dev#   3 Vendor 0x0658 Product 0x0200
  |-Dev#   4 Vendor 0x2341 Product 0x0042
  `-Dev#   5 Vendor 0x0557 Product 0x7000
    `-Dev#   6 Vendor 0x0557 Product 0x2419
Bus#  2
`-Dev#   1 Vendor 0x0e0f Product 0x8002
  `-Dev#   2 Vendor 0x8087 Product 0x800a
Bus#  3
`-Dev#   1 Vendor 0x0e0f Product 0x8002
  `-Dev#   2 Vendor 0x8087 Product 0x8002
```

This time, I see the "0bda:5411" hub and a 2nd "16c0:05df" under the hub (this is the actual hardware configuration).
At the time of the commands, the 2nd "16c0:05df" was not working at all (as if not detected), but the "0403:6001", a serial-to-usb also connected to the hub is working correctly.

Any idea why the 2 different outputs, and where it comes from ?
(In ESXi, I don't have access to sysfs)